# Adding Nodes to an IXMLNodeCollection in Delphi XE7

Tags: xml, delphi

I have been having trouble using IXMLNodeCollection interface and TXMLNodeCollection class for some time now.  I have narrowed down the problem to this.  Consider a simple XML document such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root id="27">
  <SomeItems>
    <SomeItem id="69"/>
    <SomeItem id="84"/>
    <SomeItem id="244"/>
  </SomeItems>
</Root>
```

Basically, the `Root` node contains a `SomeItems` collection of `SomeItem` nodes.  I have implemented this as three IXMLNode/iXMLNodeCollection based interfaces, with associated TXMLNode/TXMLNodeCollection cllasses like this:

```
unit XNodes;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLDoc, Xml.XMLIntf;

type
  IXMLAParent = interface;
  IXMLSomeItems = interface;
  IXMLSomeItem = interface;

  { AParent }

  IXMLAParent = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{61AB551A-F1B5-437C-A265-9FB4BBBC8A8B}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetId(Value: Integer);
    function GetSomeItems: IXMLSomeItems;

    { Methods & Properties }
    property Id: Integer read GetId write SetId;
    property SomeItems: IXMLSomeItems read GetSomeItems;
  end;

  TXMLAParent = class(TXMLNode, IXMLAParent)
  protected
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetId(Value: Integer);
    function GetSomeItems: IXMLSomeItems;

  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

  { SomeItems }

  IXMLSomeItems = interface(IXMLNodeCollection)
    ['{7071899E-8F58-4685-A908-8E4E1C13F556}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function GetSomeItem(Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
    { Methods & Properties }
    function Add: IXMLSomeItem;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
    property SomeItem[Index: Integer]: IXMLSomeItem read GetSomeItem; default;
  end;

  TXMLSomeItems = class(TXMLNodeCollection, IXMLSomeItems)
  protected
    { IXMLSomeItems }
    function GetSomeItem(Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
    function Add: IXMLSomeItem;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

  { SomeItem }

  IXMLSomeItem = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{4F1FC343-9EAD-4C33-93E1-BD511E59F44A}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetId(Value: Integer);

    { Methods & Properties }
    property Id: Integer read GetId write SetId;
  end;

  TXMLSomeItem = class(TXMLNode, IXMLSomeItem)
  protected
    { IXMLSomeItem }
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetId(Value: Integer);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;


implementation

{ TXMLAParent }

procedure TXMLAParent.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('SomeItems', TXMLSomeItems);
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLAParent.GetId: Integer;
begin
  try
    Result := AttributeNodes['id'].NodeValue;
  except
    on Exception do
      begin
        AttributeNodes['id'].NodeValue := -1;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TXMLAParent.SetId(Value: Integer);
begin
  SetAttribute('id', Value);
end;

function TXMLAParent.GetSomeItems: IXMLSomeItems;
begin
  try
    Result := ChildNodes['SomeItems'] as IXMLSomeItems;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      begin
        Result := Self.AddChild('SomeItems') as IXMLSomeItems;
      end;
  end;
end;

{ TXMLSomeItems }

procedure TXMLSomeItems.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('SomeItem', TXMLSomeItem);
  ItemTag := 'SomeItem';
  ItemInterface := IXMLSomeItem;
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLSomeItems.GetSomeItem(Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
begin
  Result := List[Index] as IXMLSomeItem;
end;

function TXMLSomeItems.Add: IXMLSomeItem;
begin
  Result := AddItem(-1) as IXMLSomeItem;
end;

function TXMLSomeItems.Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLSomeItem;
begin
  Result := AddItem(Index) as IXMLSomeItem;
end;

{ TXMLSomeItem }

procedure TXMLSomeItem.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLSomeItem.GetId: Integer;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['id'].NodeValue;
end;

procedure TXMLSomeItem.SetId(Value: Integer);
begin
  SetAttribute('id', Value);
end;
end.
```

Now in my app, I create an `IXMLDocument` using `IXMLParent` as the root node, then I want to create some nodes in the `SomeItems` collection in that document.  Here is my code that adds a single node

```
par := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('Root', TXMLAParent, '') as IXMLAParent;
par.OwnerDocument.Options := par.OwnerDocument.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
par.Id := 27;
WriteLn('NewXML:');
WriteLn(par.XML);

WriteLn('NumChild: ', par.SomeItems.Count);
item := par.SomeItems.Add;
item.Id := 69;
WriteLn('Add Item:');
WriteLn(par.XML);
WriteLn('NumItems: ', par.SomeItems.Count);
try
  WriteLn('Does this fail? ', par.SomeItems[0].Id);
except
  WriteLn('Yes, that failed!');
end;
```

Instead of printing `NumItems: 1`, it says there are 4 items.  Furthermore, an exception is thrown when trying to access the first node in the collection!  It seems the `par.SomeItems[0]` construct doesn't return a IXMLSomeItem reference.  Why?

The really odd thing is that, if I save the XML document, then reload it, it now works!  Here is the entire program:

program test;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, ActiveX, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLDoc, Xml.XMLIntf, XNodes;

var
  par: IXMLAParent;
  item: IXMLSomeItem;
  doc: IXMLDocument;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);

  par := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('Root', TXMLAParent, '') as IXMLAParent;
  par.OwnerDocument.Options := par.OwnerDocument.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  par.Id := 27;
  WriteLn('NewXML:');
  WriteLn(par.XML);

  WriteLn('NumChild: ', par.SomeItems.Count);
  item := par.SomeItems.Add;
  item.Id := 69;
  WriteLn('Add Item:');
  WriteLn(par.XML);
  WriteLn('NumItems: ', par.SomeItems.Count);
  try
    WriteLn('Does this fail? ', par.SomeItems[0].Id);
  except
    WriteLn('Yes, that failed!');
  end;

  doc := par.OwnerDocument;
  doc.Active := True;
  doc.Options := doc.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  doc.SaveToFile('temp.xml');

  par := nil;
  par := LoadXMLDocument('temp.xml').GetDocBinding('Root', TXMLAParent, '') as IXMLAParent;
  par.OwnerDocument.Options := par.OwnerDocument.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  WriteLn('OpenXML:');
  WriteLn(par.XML);
  WriteLn('NumItems: ', par.SomeItems.Count);
  WriteLn('This works: ', par.SomeItems[0].Id);
  par := nil;

  CoUninitialize;
end.
```

Here is the entire output from that program:

```
NewXML:
<Root id="27"/>
NumChild: 0
Add Item:
<Root id="27">
  <SomeItems>
    <SomeItem id="69"/>
  </SomeItems>
</Root>
NumItems: 4
Yes, that failed!
OpenXML:
<Root id="27">
        <SomeItems>
                <SomeItem id="69"/>
        </SomeItems>
</Root>
NumItems: 1
This works: 69
```

(Note that this program throws an exception at the end; I don't care about that, as this is a contrived demo.  Also, the odd increased indentation is annoying, but not crucial; if you know how to prevent that, well, bonus points!)  This saving/reading workaround has worked in the past, but it is clumsy in practice.  I would really like to be able to add to the `IXMLNodeCollection` then be able to access the nodes in code, immediately after creating them.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: On the face of it, all the classes that you derive from library xml classes are needless and should be removed. You have taken a wrong turn.

Comment: When I started this project 10 years ago(!), I didn't know how to use this library, and it is one of the more confusing; docs didn't give a big picture, IMHO.  Anyway, this approach (interface/class) was generated by Delphi back in 2007 from my schema I had originally developed; I don't remember the tool, but it generated a .pas unit with a comment "XML Data Binding", noting when it was generated, from what .xsd schema, and noting it has saved settings to a .xdb file.  Being new to IXMLxxx interfaces and TXMLxxx classes, I did what I told.  So the classes are useless? What should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Instead of printing NumItems: 1, it says there are 4 items. Furthermore, an exception is thrown when trying to access the first node in the collection! It seems the par.SomeItems[0] construct doesn't return a IXMLSomeItem reference. Why?

One word: **whitespace**.

You are enabling the `doNodeAutoIndent` flag, which inserts indentation whitespace between elements.  XML represents whitespace using extra nodes in the DOM, eg:

```
Root
|_ whitespace
|_ SomeItems
    |_ whitespace
    |_ SomeItem
    |_ whitespace
    |_ SomeItem
    |_ whitespace
    |_ SomeItem
    |_ whitespace
```

> The really odd thing is that, if I save the XML document, then reload it, it now works!

When you load an XML document, the parser discards whitespace if the `(T|I)XMLDocument.ParseOptions` property does not have the `poPreserveWhiteSpace` flag enabled, so those extra whitespace nodes would not exist in the DOM.

```
Root
|_ SomeItems
    |_ SomeItem
    |_ SomeItem
    |_ SomeItem
```

> Note that this program throws an exception at the end

You are not releasing all of the interfaces before calling `CoUnitialize()`.  Non-nil interfaces are automatically released when they go out of scope, which in this case is after the `end`.  You are setting the `par` variable to nil but not the `item` variable. Interfaces are reference counted, and the XML element nodes have a reference to their parent node and the owning document, so the `par` object is being kept alive by the non-nil `item` variable.

> I would really like to be able to add to the IXMLNodeCollection then be able to access the nodes in code, immediately after creating them.

That is why `Add()` returns the newly added node, so just use it as-is, you don't need to use the `Nodes[]` property to retrieve it.  If you do use `Nodes[]`, you need to have a good understanding of the DOM's layout.

Comment: Thanks for these insights; they sure make things a lot clearer!  With them, I think I may just be able to get things working again!

However, what I meant about accessing the nodes is not immediately after adding the nodes, but accessing them after the document has been returned to the caller, who then may want to iterate over the nodes in the collection.  I think your key insight, whitespace, is all that I had forgotten about XML!  After all, when I look at a printout of an XML document, I tend to think of the whitespace as being there simply for formatting!  I forgot it can be in XML!

Comment: I can't look at this until tomorrow; I'll update my question (probably will be checking the Solved check, I expect!) 

Thanks!

Comment: @Bob if you are returning an XML document for some other piece of code to iterate through, I would recommend disabling the whitespace generation. If the caller wants whitespace, such as for human consumable output, then it can add its own whitespace as needed, such as with [`FormatXmlData()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.FormatXMLData).

Comment: Yeah, I think so too; that is the gist of your one word answer: whitespace!  I like that, in addition to the pithy, you add the background with your answer!  I can hardly wait to check this all out tomorrow - whitespace really was the exact thing I was missing in my thinking, I'm rather sure...

Comment: Yup, that did it, Remy!  Thanks again!